# Update SQL Server database with SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I have somehow a problem to update my SQL Server database. I got an "Update" button so the user can change values manually in a DataGridView and then should click a button to save the changes to the database. I use the "Update" command for that but don't know how to manage it.

The button:

```
 private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {     
     sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDatAdapter);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = datTable;
     sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
     sqlDatAdapter.Update(datTable);    
 }
```

The database gets loaded via another function. In my code I get a `NullReferenceException`.

How can I catch the existing DataGrid and then register the users changes?

When I define the `SqlDatAdapter` in the method then the exception doesn't occur anymore but it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: On which line exactly? Did you debug your code? And, 
[What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I get it in "sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);" Yes I know what a NullReferenceException is but I don't know how to solve it in that case. I tried some things but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used

```
 DataTable datTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

and now the Exception isn't there anymore.